# Could we form the homotopy category of a dg-category by inverting homotopic invertible morphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, localization, chain-complexes

Let $k$ be a field and $\mathcal{C}$ be a dg-category over $k$. It is standard to define the homotopy category $H^0(\mathcal{C})$ as the category consisting the same objects as $\mathcal{C}$ but morphisms between two objects $x$ and $y$ are defined as
$$
H^0(\mathcal{C})(x,y):=Z^0(\mathcal{C})(x,y)/B^0(\mathcal{C})(x,y).
$$

We could also consider the category $Z^0(\mathcal{C})$ and the class $W$ of homotopic invertible morphisms in $Z^0(\mathcal{C})$. More precisely, 
$$
W=\{f\in Z^0(\mathcal{C})(x,y) \text{ for some }x \text{ and }y~|~f \text{ is invertible in } H^0(\mathcal{C})(x,y)\}.
$$

We could localize the category $Z^0(\mathcal{C})$ by formally inverting $W$ and obtain a category $W^{-1}Z^0(\mathcal{C})$. There is a natural functor $W^{-1}Z^0(\mathcal{C})\to H^0(\mathcal{C})$.

> > My question is: Is $W^{-1}Z^0(\mathcal{C})$ equivalent to $H^0(\mathcal{C})$?

Comment: This certainly needs some hypotheses on the dg-category (consider a one object dg-category: not all quotients by ideals are localizations!). Maybe pretriangulated is enough?

Comment: Proposition 5.17 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01515 has one possible answer to your question.  (One must pass to the homotopy category on both sides.)